# Adding Conversation Memory to Xenova/LaMini-T5-61M Browser-based Model in JS

Tags: huggingface-transformers, langchain, onnx, large-language-model, language-model

I'm currently working with the browser-based model in JavaScript, specifically 'text2text-generation' by Xenova/LaMini-T5-61M. My goal is to implement conversation memory functionality using Langchain. Could someone provide guidance or code examples on how to integrate Langchain for conversation memory in this context?